# openssl installer not copying dlls to windows system folder

Tags: openssl

I have downloaded windows openssl (Win32OpenSSL_Light-1_0_1h.exe).

When installing it prompts if the dll files are to be copied to the **windows system directory**.  I select Yes.  But after the install the date/time of the files in the c:\windows\system32 do not update.

Should I just copy the ssleay32.dll and libssl32.dll from C:\OpenSSL-Win32 to system32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they don't copy, you can just do it yourself.

Afterward, register the dlls using `regsvr32 libssl32.dll` and `regsvr32 ssleay32.dll` so they can be used.

Comment: Thank you.  Is it common they don't copy?  I am actually quite suprised they didn't.  When I first did this the installer threw a message it could not copy files because they were in use.  But when I stopped my webserver and hit the "retry" button they did.

Comment: I haven't really messed with OpenSSL installers all that much, but I do see it quite commonly as the installer doesn't always prompt if the file's in use or something prevents it from copying the new one.